# Adding margins in a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextarea

So I have a `JTextArea` which shows the text right from the top left corner. I want some margin on all 4 sides, so there's some space between text and boundary of the area.

I have researched a lot and could not find any solution. How can I do it?

Also, I was thinking maybe put up a label on all 4 sides to create dummy margin. How can I create a `JLabel` with certain width and height?

Comment: May be I dont understand your question correctly. Can't you use `setMargin()`?

Comment: Exactly what @Smit said. [Relevant javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setMargin%28java.awt.Insets%29). The [`Insets`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Insets.html) are just 4 values in pixels that represent the size of the margin for the top, bottom, left, and right sides.

Comment: AFAICT, this is what he is looking for. Setting a border is not as good because it would drop the default expected border. A compound border could help work around the issue but its lamer than using setMargin

Answer (score 12, accepted):

May be I dont understand your question correctly. However you can use setMargin()

```
// set the margin for all four sides
tt.setMargin( new Insets(10,10,10,10) ); // tt is JTextArea instance
```

Some Important Links

[1. setMargin API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setMargin%28java.awt.Insets%29)

[2. Class Insets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Insets.html)

Comment: (@Smit, following our previous comments): I prefer not setting a border because it removes the expected textfield border. If you still want to use a border, you can combine the existing border of the textfield with a compount border and an empty border as its inner or outer border (depending on the effect you are trying to achieve). If it's the inner one, I prefer using setMargin(), simpler and more robust.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet +1 Thanks for info. If you want you can also add this  answer.